# How to execute any .exe by using a batch file if folder name contains spaces

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am using the following code:

```
for %%i in ("C:\Users\bvino_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RapidLoadToolV2\RapidLoadToolV2\bin\Debug\RapidLoadToolV2.exe") do start "" /b "%%i"
```

But although using double quotes, it is taking path upto "C:\Users\bvino_000\Documents\Visual" and showing error.
If i change folder name, then the command works properly.
But i cant do that
Plzz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
start "" /b "C:\Users\bvino_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RapidLoadToolV2\RapidLoadToolV2\bin\Debug\RapidLoadToolV2.exe"
```

Comment: Can u help me in one more thing..
actually now exe is running properly.
but it is showing error in building the code.
I am using the following code:

@echo off     
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"       
cd\           
msbuild "C:\Users\bvino_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RapidLoadToolV2\RapidLoadToolV2.sln" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"             
Pause

Comment: Sorry, but I have no clue of Visual Studio :(

Comment: I am just asking the method to build the code using batch file

Comment: `is showing error in building the code` this seems to be an error message by VS.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly happily for me.

I suspect that my edit - intended to show conventional highlighting - corrected the matter and that OP has `...\Visual` on one physical line and `Studio...` on the next. The entire quoted string should be on the same line, but it **IS** acceptable to have newlines directly before the first quote an directly after the second, so that the quoted-string is on a line by itself. The open-parenthesis must appear on the same physical line as the `IN` and the close on the same physical line as the `DO`, as must the executable to be invoked (or an open parenthesis to begin a block). Line-terminal carets (`^`) may be used to continue lines in some circumstances, but their use is rare and touchy.

`%%i` will acquire the set of quotes, so re-quoting it may not be required.